# Bloch states at the zone boundary

Tags: solid-state-physics

How do I show that in 1D the Bloch states at the zone boundary $\left(k=\pm\frac{\pi}{a}\right)$ form standing waves? How is it clear, that there is a high- and a low energy state for a finite potential? I know these pictures of the two standing waves:

[image: standing electron waves]

but how do I come to this?

Comment: Think back to the definition of a standing wave. What is the group velocity of such a state?